# Futures Timeout Exception crashes the Platform

Tags: scala, playframework

We use futures in our playframework when reading data from database. It will timeout after 700 ms.However,sometimes it will throw an Timeout exception and crashes the whole platform.

Should we just increase the timeout period or dont use future when reading data from database?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "kills the platform" ? In your logs we can only see that the exception is caught by play framework. 
Also the timeout you show is `700 ms` whereas in the logs, it's indicated to be `10 seconds`.
On another level, it's a bad practice to use `Await.result`, you should return a `Future` here

Comment: I rephrased the question. Could you please let me know how to return Future?

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `Await.result` part in the function. The signature of the function will become:

```
def getUser(...): Future[User]
```

You will then have to modify the impacted parts of your codebase accordingly.